# tc server failing to start in SpringsourceToolSuite

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat

Just today my STS instance is failing to start tcserver.

We are using tc server 2.7.1

Starting up the server in Eclipse gives:

```
23/08/2012 11:07:29 AM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tc Runtime property decoder using memory-based key
23/08/2012 11:07:29 AM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tcServer Runtime property decoder has been initialized in 363 ms
23/08/2012 11:07:30 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
23/08/2012 11:07:30 AM com.springsource.tcserver.serviceability.rmi.JmxSocketListener init
INFO: Started up JMX registry on 127.0.0.1:6969 in 113 ms
23/08/2012 11:07:30 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1197 ms
```

And then there is no more logging.

Eclipse times out after 120 seconds

If I increase the timeout to 520 seconds that makes no difference.

The only thing changed between today and yesterday is that the Subclipse plugin was updated.

Please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that one of the JNDI data sources (for an INGRESS database) was not responding.

It would have been nice if tc server logged an error stating a connection timeout.

Commenting out the entry allowed tc server to startup correctly